# Echo php code doesn't print anything

Tags: php, html, postgresql, echo

I am using following code to show in a table database results:

```
<table cellspacing="0" width="700">
    <tbody>
            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT id1, id2, id3, id4, id5 FROM table";
            $result = pg_query($db, $sql);
            if (pg_num_rows($result) != 0)
            {
                while($results_row = pg_fetch_row($result))
                {
                    echo '
                    <tr>
                        <td id="id1"> '.$results_row[1].'  </td>
                        <td id="id2"> '.$results_row[2].' </td>
                        <td id="id3"> '.$results_row[3].' </td>
                        <td id="id4"> '.$results_row[4].' </td>
                        <td id="id5"> ' if (.$results_row[5]. != "") 
                                      {'.$results_row[5].'}' </td>

                    </tr>
                    ';
                }
            }
            ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Obviously I'm having problems with "if" statement so nothing appears on the screen... Also I'd like to ask why dots are used in both sides of $results_row. Is it because it's an array?

Comment: Both side dots of $results_row indicate concatenation with string and your database value

Comment: the problem is in your `if` statement .Two tips : _1._ it doesn't make sense _2._ invalid syntax.

Comment: dots are assigned for concatenation.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking about the very basics of PHP syntax. Better resources exist on the internet.

Comment: `.` are used to split text from variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
echo '
    <tr>
        <td id="id1"> '.$results_row[1].'  </td>
        <td id="id2"> '.$results_row[2].' </td>
        <td id="id3"> '.$results_row[3].' </td>
        <td id="id4"> '.$results_row[4].' </td>
        <td id="id5"> '; 

    if($results_row[5] != "")  { echo $results_row[5]; }

echo '
        </td>
    </tr>';
```

- untested

Comment: Appending to a variable then echoing that would be another option. The ternary solutions in the other answers are good too.

Answer (score 2):

You can not make if statment inside echo. Please change if to this:,

```
. ($results_row[5] != "" ?  $results_row[5] : '') .
```

Answer (score 2):

it seems you are severely confused about string concatenation. string concatenation is when you join two or more strings. take an example:

```
$string1 = "<td id='id1'>";
$results_row[1] = "some string";
$string2 = "</td>";

$concatenated_string = $string1 ." ". $result_row ." ". $string2; 
echo $concatenated_string;
```

the output would be: ‹td id='id1'› some string ‹/td›

the dot (.) joins multiple strings to create one complete string, in other words, concatenate them.

As for your `if`, look at your last `if` inside the while loop.
you have: `if (.$results_row[5]. != "")`

while it should be `if ( $results_row[5] != "" )`
you have two useless dots.

Now, posting a complete code in here will do nothing but make the questioner lazy, so dig deeper into php string manipulation and

happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

the . is for string concantation. You cannot have an if condition within a string.

You may instead use the ternary oporator:

```
while($results_row = pg_fetch_row($result))
            {
                echo '
                <tr>
                    <td id="id1"> '.$results_row[1].'  </td>
                    <td id="id2"> '.$results_row[2].' </td>
                    <td id="id3"> '.$results_row[3].' </td>
                    <td id="id4"> '.$results_row[4].' </td>
                    <td id="id5"> '.($results_row[5] != "")? $results_row[5] : ''.</td>

                </tr>
                ';
            }
```

Or refactor your loop to exist php mode:

```
while($results_row = pg_fetch_row($result)): ?>

                <tr>
                    <td id="id1"> <?php echo $results_row[1];?>  </td>
                    <td id="id2"> <?php echo$results_row[2];?> </td>
                    <td id="id3"> <?php echo$results_row[3];?> </td>
                    <td id="id4"> <?php echo$results_row[4];?> </td>
                    <td id="id5"> <?php if (.$results_row[5]. != ""){ echo $results_row[5];}?></td>

                </tr>

<?php endwhile;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<table cellspacing="0" width="700">
    <tbody>
            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT id1, id2, id3, id4, id5 FROM table";
            $result = pg_query($db, $sql);
            if (pg_num_rows($result) != 0)
            {
                while($results_row = pg_fetch_row($result))
                {
                    echo "
                    <tr>
                        <td id='id1'> ".$results_row[1]."  </td>
                        <td id="id2"> ".$results_row[2]." </td>
                        <td id="id3"> ".$results_row[3]." </td>
                        <td id="id4"> ".$results_row[4]." </td>
                        <td id="id5"> ".(($results_row[5] != "")?$results_row[5]:"")."</td>".
                    "</tr>";
                }
            }
            ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Hopefully, it's right.